# How to pass a list from method to another method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

How to pass below action to another action in order to export it in excel sheet
,I need to pass VL list to another action

```
public ActionResult Details(int S)
{
    SLMEntitiesDB dbContext = new SLMEntitiesDB();
                var VL = (from U in dbContext.Users
                  join P in dbContext.Products
                  on U.PID equals P.PID
                  where P.PID == U.PID
                  select new UP()
                  {
                      UserO = U,
                      ProductO = P
                  }).Where(U => U.UserO.LID == S).ToList();
TempData["Exc"] = VL; 
    return View(VL);
}
```

and the other action within the same controller, but it's not working

```
public void ExportToExcel()
        {

            var V = TempData["Exc"] as List;
            ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");
            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "UserName";
            int rowStart = 1;
            foreach (var item in V)// here is the error 
            {
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.UserO.CN;
```

Comment: you can use RedirectToAction method and pass the VL as a parmater and handle the request in the taarget action method
return RedirectToAction(VL);

Comment: the above method is just to view this list in a view, now i want to create a button inside that view to export the list into excel sheet.

Comment: Or let's say, how i can access the above list from another action in the same class

Comment: from your other [so question\answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473379/1366179) I'm going to update my answer to use your model namespace defined there.  also, make sure you accept your own answer in that question - don't let questions remain unaccepted when they are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

you'll create another Function\Action on your controller and pass the data from your view to it. Depending on the size of the data, you could do that as a QueryString (note: type `.ToString()` considerations, html encoding in that approach), but it's more likely you'll store the instance server-side, using `TempData[key]` or something similar.

The other aspect of what you're attempting to do (export an Excel File) will be handled by the added Action; However, instead of you handling the entire Response writing in the scope of your action, I recommend you define a type that inherits the `FileResult` type - where you handle `HttpResponseBase` in the overloaded `WriteFile` function (example below).

#### XLSFileResult

This sample type will actually be writing Comma Separate Value (CSV) content, but the `Content-Type` (coupled with `Content-Disposition`) will 'indicate' to the client that it is an excel file - the `Response` will respond with an ".xls" file.

Note: the filename and extension in this sample are actually defined at it's initialization - in the action of the controller.

```
public class XLSFileResult : FileResult
{
    public XLSFileResult() : base(@"application/vnd.ms-excel")
    {
        Data = new List<UP>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<UP> Data { get; set; }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        // note: you'll want to handle this better; I'm just choosing a property of each complex type.
        string[] lines = Data.Select(d => string.Join(", ", d.UserO.UserName , d.ProductO.PName)).ToArray();
        byte[] buffer = response.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
        response.BinaryWrite(buffer);                       
    }
}
```

#### Sample Action\Function on the Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int S)
{
    SLMEntitiesDB dbContext = new SLMEntitiesDB();
    var VL = (from U in dbContext.Users
              join P in dbContext.Products
              on U.PID equals P.PID
              where P.PID == U.PID
              select new UP()
              {
                  UserO = U,
                  ProductO = P
              }).Where(U => U.UserO.LID == S).ToList();
    return View(VL);
}

protected FileResult HandleDataToFileResult(IEnumerable<UP> data)
{
    return new XLSFileResult()
    {
        Data = data,
        FileDownloadName = "MyFile.xls" //by virtue of this assignment, a 'Content-Disposition' Response.Header is added to HttpResponseBase
    };
}

public FileResult GenerateFile()
{
    var data = (IEnumerable<UP>)TempData["GenerateFile"];
    return HandleDataToFileResult(data);
}
```

#### Razor Page

In this sample of the razor page, we'll use a `ActionLink`...

```
@using SLMDemo0.Models
@model IEnumerable<UP>

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Details";
  //Review TempData, it's session data that clears at the end of the next request
  TempData["GenerateFile"] = Model.ToArray();
}
...

@Html.ActionLink("GenerateFile", "GenerateFile");
```

Comment: Thank you brett very much for your answer, I'm sorry since I'm completely new to mvc I didn't understand well your answer( especially the first part for XLSFileResult
)

Comment: regarding the first part which is public class XLSFileResult : FileResult, this should be in my controller right?

Comment: not the definition of the type (`public class`) itself.. but the usage of it should be (`new` instance).